# sensu standalone checks on remote servers that do not have rabbitmq access

Tags: python, rabbitmq, monitoring, pika, sensu

I have a setup for monitoring right now where the alerts are coming in from thousands of nodes in a multitude of ways, the methods available are dictated by the network's owner due to various security mechanisms.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can receive alert data external to Sensu and push to sensu using Python's pika library? If so, can you point me to the docs that cover this? I've searched Google and could not find anything useful. Thanks!

I found my answer, posting here in case anyone else has similar questions:
http://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/external_result_input#documentation

Comment: It's best to post answers as an actual answer to the question, and then accept it to indicate that it helped with your problem.  I've suggested an edit to your original question and posted the link you found as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is available here: http://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/external_result_input#documentation.